# How can I change the html form fields mapping to serialier fields value in DRF?

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have these nested serializers, in which the fields are not appropriately maped to html form fields in default browsable API page of django rest_framework, I have customized the representation of the response, and now I want to map those values to the appropriate HTML form fields

Below is my `serializer`

```py
class NestedtLocationSerializer(gis_serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        geo_field = 'geometry'
        fields = (
            'type',
            'is_mobile',
            'name',
            'address',
            'geometry',
        )


class NestedFloorplanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FloorPlan
        fields = (
            'floor',
            'image',
        )


class DeviceLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = NestedtLocationSerializer()
    floorplan = NestedFloorplanSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DeviceLocation
        fields = (
            'location',
            'floorplan',
            'indoor',
        )
```

with the above serilaizers, I am getting this:-
Response:-

[image]

But in the html form fields the values of `is_mobile`, `type`, `name` are not loading in the html form fields:-
[image]

Is there any way, I can control the default mapping of these values to appropriate serializer fields in the django-rest-framework browsable page??

Comment: How is the form rendered?

Comment: It's the Browsable Page which drf provides by default, I didn't got your question clearly??

Comment: Sorry it's my bad, I thought the form you are showing was written by you

Comment: Use custom `BrowsableAPIRenderer` class

Comment: `address` is not loading in HTML too. isn't it?

do you edit `BrowsableAPIRenderer` or something like that?

Comment: I think it's related to `gis_serializers` package and not to drf